# To select all the accordion-group in between the selected accordion-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap accordion-group as following :

```
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span1">
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
</div>
<div class="span11"> ... </div>
</div>
</div>
```

there are so many rows of accordion group.
Say i have selected any one. (Now the $(div.accordion-group) is added with "selected" class and input element get property of "checked")

Now i want when i select any other accordion-group element WITH SHIFT KEY PRESSED,
then all the in-between accordion-group elements should also get selected automatically.

I am doing the following :

```
if (e && e.originalEvent.type === "click" && e.originalEvent.shiftKey === true) {
            $(e.target).prevUntil(':checked', 'input[type="checkbox"].select-row').prop('checked', true);
        $(e.target).prevUntil('.accordion-group.selected', 'input[type="checkbox"].select-row').addClass('selected');

          }
```

I have also ensured that the code inside 'if' get executed by logging console.
But code has no effect.

How do i achieve my goal?